# Cannot mount glusterfs client ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, glusterfs

So I am totally new to whole GlusterFS world, have been researching it because I need a shared drive between EC2 instances. I have 2 ubuntu webservers which connect to third instance which only hosts MySQL. I want shared drive between 2 webservers so I set up 2 more Ubuntu servers to create GlusterFS replication type set up. I went through the doc that showed how to set it up.

I then went to webservers and installed glusterfs-client, added entry in fstab but I do see anything when I use df -h command. So I tried manually mounting the drive and it said mount was unsuccessful and to look into the log files. This is what I see in the log files. [image: log file]
I have no idea on how to resolve this. Search results for similar error point to Red Hat issues but none for Ubuntu. Any ideas on how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this issue thanks to the freenode channel. I had a version issue, removed the client added sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gluster/glusterfs-3.8 on client to match server version.

Answer (score 0):

Basics first.

1. All nodes should be aware of every other node. Localhost won't work, use other names. ex: n1.
2. If you are running in containerised version then the volume/storage should also be connected.

Check the /etc/hosts and add the ip-address with their dns resl name as well.

Steps to configure.

1. clone the repo
2. 

```sh
sudo ./autogen.sh
```

3. 

```sh
sudo ./configure
```

4. Switch to super user

```sh
make
```

5. 

```sh
make install
```

6. Run the gluster daemon to interact with the kernel space.

```sh
glusterd
```

7. Create volume

```sh
gluster volume create vol_name n1:/vol_directory/{brick1,...brick9}
gluster volume start vol_name
```

8. Mount user dir to gfs volume

```sh
mount -t glusterfs n1:/vol_name /mnt/mount_dir
```

This is the basic use of GlusterFS with default distributed volume.
Now one can store data from mount point to gluster volume.
Read more at https://www.docs.gluster.com